# Getting total (ignoring overflow) width in CSS

Tags: html, css, width, overflow, marquee

Is there a way to get the total width of an element in CSS - i.e., what its width would be if it weren't `overflow: hidden`?

Background: I'm trying to set up some elements that will get a marquee-style scrolling effect when hovered. I have this mostly working by animating the `text-indent` property, but I haven't figured out the right amount to use for `text-indent`. (If I use `100%`, it uses the width of the container, not what the width of the item needs to be.)

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/3yy89abq/2/)

Comment: If there is no problem to have hidden elements in your code, you can duplicate the same item outside the container with visibility: none; and overflow: visible; styles and take it's width with JavaScript. This will get you the width, but in this case you have the limitation of what the browser's width is on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to set text-indent relative to the width of the element it's applied to unless you know its width, as far as I can tell. (Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent))

For your purposes, I would suggest either animating the width of a `::before` pseudo-element:

```
.marquee {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.marquee::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0; /* This property can be animated to push the content to the right  */
}
```

Or if you don't mind the extra element, you could put the text in an inner element and animate its [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) property with `translateX`, which would most likely be slightly more performant.